# Unity Xenial add menu item to system menu

Tags: 16.04, unity

I would like to add a menu item to the system menu, `the cog`, to turn off my screen using `xset dpms force off`.  How would I do this?

Comment: Excellent question. I have a computer that people keep suspending simply because they want the screen to turn off. It looks like the answer will be found in /usr/share/unity/indicators/com.canonical.indicator.session.